# How to load Combobox-items on dropdown

Tags: wpf, command, dropdown

I need to work with an excel workbook, with some worsheets.
To load the available worksheets into a combobox, I need to open the workbook and iterate through all sheets and add them to the combobox. This cost a lot of time, the user needs to wait for. If the user doesn't want to change the preloaded property, this time is waisted. So I only want to fill in the listitems when needed but show the preselected property, that was loaded from a settingsfile on startup of the app.

So is there a way to load the items on dropdown? Or better, how can I bind a command that is triggerd on dropdown, to load the items?

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Worksheet}" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkSheets}" x:Name="cbWorkSheet" Padding="4">
```

... oh, I know how to bind a command to a button so I need a special tip for the combobox, not for commands in general :)

**UPDATE**
I solved to trigger the "loading" and the List is filled but I need to show the last selected value (that is loaded on startup as the bound property Worksheet)

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="cbWorkSheet" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Worksheet}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding WorkSheets}" 
    IsEditable="True"
    Padding="4">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=cbWorkSheet}">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadBACnetWsCombobox}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

With that Binding, the Combobox remains empty till I dropdown it :(

Comment: Can u post the code where worksheet property is updated.

Comment: hmm... perhaps I need to clarify this. I have that property, that was selected on a former use of the app. So if the user doesn't want to change this property, ther is no need to fill the listitems of the combobox. The property is bound to the SelectedItem of the combobox, so it should be shown on startup. If the user wants to change this property, he has to select another from the combobox and now is the point to fill the itemslist.

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer: Incorrect, Posted 2020/06/02:**

If you need SelectedItem populated before you open the dropdown, then you should probably change your EventTrigger's EventName from `DropDownOpened` to be `Loaded`.

That way, before the combobox is shown to the user, `LoadBACnetWsComboBox` will run, and hopefully your `Worksheet` will be set.  Then, the combobox will be shown to the user.

**Modified Answer, Posted 2020/06/03:**

If you want to just populate the initial displayed text, you can always set the `Text` property of the combobox.  It will get overridden once you do selections from the drop down.

```
<ComboBox
   ...
   Text="{Binding MyInitialValue}">
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain it right. The selected property was loaded on startup of the app, from a settings-file. It shows the selection of the combobox, of the last use. So I only want to display this value, without loading the listitems, because that loading costs about 2 seconds, that is waisted time, if noone wants to change the selection. So my goal, show a value in empty combobox and fill listitems when dropping down.